# Not Retreiving The Image from json using asynctask

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I want to get image url from a json by using Asynctask and set it on an ImageView by the help of RecyclerView.But when i am executing the code it shows nothing ,here is my Json file

```
[
  {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
    "url": "http://placehold.it/600/92c952",
    "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/92c952"
  },
  {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam",
    "url": "http://placehold.it/600/771796",
    "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/771796"
  }

]
```

Here is My MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDivider(MainActivity.this));
    RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
}


private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, String> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        StringBuffer chaine = new StringBuffer("");

        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                chaine.append(line);
            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String result = chaine.toString();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        JB jb = new JB();
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String image = jObject.getString("url");
                jb.setAndroid_image_url(image);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is my RecyclerAdapter

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
ArrayList<JB> jbs;
private Context context;


public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.image_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(itemView);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Picasso.with(context).load(jbs.get(position).getAndroid_image_url()).resize(120, 60).into(holder.imageView);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

    }
}
```

}

I am using picaso to load the photo to ImageView

Comment: Do you have your recycler adapter in main activity itself?

Comment: update your AsyncTask class as `extends AsyncTask<Object,Void,String>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing Something, i have done some changes. update your code

**Update onPostExecute**

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    ArrayList<JB> jb = new ArrayList<JB>();
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String image = jObject.getString("url");
            jb.setAndroid_image_url(image);
        }

  // remove below code from your OnCreate

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDivider(MainActivity.this));
        RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, jb);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

**Update RecyclerView Adapter Constructor**

```
 public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<JB> jb) {
        this.context = context;
        this.jbs= jb;
    }
```

Comment: where did that method come from ->
`jb.setAndroid_image_url(image)`?

Comment: @Anirudh But you are not setting the adapter anywhere??

Comment: @Dennis its from my javabean class

Answer (score 0):

You have to create ArrayList of JB class, then pass to recyclerview adapter.

```
    ArrayList<JB> jbArray = new ArrayList();
    JB jb;
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            jb = new JB();
            JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String image = jObject.getString("url");
            jb.setAndroid_image_url(image);
            jbArray.add(jb);
        }
    recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this ,jbArray);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());
    }
```

In RecyclerViewAdapter, change constructor.

```
public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<JB> jbs) {
    this.context = context;
    this.jbs = jbs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your array

```
ArrayList<JB> yourarray = new ArrayList;

@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            JB jb = new JB();
            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    jb = new JB();
                    JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String image = jObject.getString("url");
                    jb.setAndroid_image_url(image);
                    yourarray.add(jb);


                }

        RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,yourarray);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter,yourarray);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());
            }
    }
```

Update your adapter constructor

```
public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<JB> jbs) {
    this.context = context;
    this.jbs=jbs;
}
```

Comment: Are you passing your arraylist to adapter?

Comment: Now i am getting this error:                                                              
            Error:(98, 29) error: method setAdapter in class RecyclerView cannot be applied to given types;
required: Adapter
found: RecyclerViewAdapter,ArrayList<JB>
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: This means that the *number or types* of arguments/parameter that you are passing while *calling/invoking* the method is/are **not same** as the one defined in the **method definition**

Comment: @A.Pant  
RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,yourarray);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter,yourarray);

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to use ArrayList of JB, because in onPostExecute you create one object of JB and overwrite data in each loop iteration.

Second, you don't set your data set in adapter. Adapter always return 0 in getItemCount method. Try something like:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<JB> jbs;
    private Context context;

    public setData(ArrayList<JB> list) {
        jbs = list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    <...>

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return jbs != null ? jbs.size() : 0;
    }
}
```

And in onPostExecute:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    ArrayList<JB> jbList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JB curJb = new JB();
            JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String image = jObject.getString("url");
            curJb.setAndroid_image_url(image);
            jbList.add(curJb);
        }
    recyclerViewAdapter.setData(jbList); //don't forget make recycleViewAdapter available in this scope
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why this is happening?It's still not showing anything

Comment: Idk what's wrong with your code. I show you pattern how you have to do. It's simple task. Try to read [link](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=ru) and don't ctrl+c, ctrl+v.